# yum install svn but not working

Tags: linux, yum

I wanted to install svn but I get the following message when I do `yum install svn`:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: mirror.nbrc.ac.in
 * base: mirror.nbrc.ac.in
 * extras: mirror.nbrc.ac.in
 * updates: mirror.fibergrid.in
Setting up Install Process
No package tomcat available.
Nothing to do
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) first and the learn [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That makes it easier for us to help you.  In particular, it is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

The package name isn't `svn` but `subversion`. `yum install subversion` should do.

Better try to search a package with `yum search $PACKAGENAME` before you try to install something.